# 3D marketplace for dummies

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, rendering, blender, 3dsmax

I'm just starting to do 3D and I want more experienced people to answer these questions:

Why do people buy 3D models? What are the problems after buying models? Why do buyers buy from certain sellers? What is important for them when buying? What do they want during work, what do they want after? What does the buying process look like? What is your experience in 3D and how did you start? Answer these questions as meaningfully as possible.How to understand what model the market needs? Are there any utilities for analyzing the market of 3D models?
I ask these questions in order to make money in my favorite business and not die of hunger: D

Comment: This is off topic for SO, try posting on gamedev.stackexchange instead